# What is the explicit definition of this phrase in this theorem?

Tags: category-theory, definition

From Mac Lane's Category Theory, what exactly is being assumed in the statement of this theorem?  What does the enclosed red box in the below picture mean?

I can see that $C$ has equalizers of all pairs of arrows means every pair of arrows in $C$ has an equalizer, but I don't understand what the next part is saying.  Can someone EXPLITICTLY explain what this means?

---

[image]

Comment: If $J$ has three objects and four arrows, then you need all ternary and quaternary products. If $J$ has countably infinite many objects and arrows then you need all products of a countable list of objects, etc.

Comment: Can you give an example?  What do you mean by "you need all..."?

Comment: "You need all...." means that you need all those products to exist. For the ternary case, you would need all products $A \times B \times C$ to exist.  Products can be indexed by sets, and the cardinality of the index set is what's relevant here.

Comment: @Randall So if $J$ has three objects $\{i,j,k\}$ and four arrows (four assuming you mean excluding the identity arrows in this count) $\{e,f,g,h\}$ then the only products that exist in $C$ are the triples and quadruples via the permutations of $\{i,j,k\}$ and $\{e,f,g,h\}$?

Comment: The "only"?  No.

Comment: @Randall What are the other products?

Comment: Depends on the category.  They might "all" be there for all I know.  The theorem is telling you when colimits exist, which depends on the shape of $J$.  It's a sufficient condition.

Comment: I don't understand why it would depend on the structure of $J$, If $c=c_1 \times c_2 \dots \times c_n$ is some product in $C$, then what does it mean that this product is indexed by the set obj($J$) or arr($J$)?  Does it mean that the indexes are actually elements of one of these sets?

Comment: @Randall In the first example you gave, what categories are the factors of $A \times B \times C$ objects of?  And if they're objects of the category $C$, how is the product indexed by obj$(J)$ or arr$(J)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We take products of objects in a category indexed by a set.  This is all he is saying:  if products always exist for index sets of *certain* sizes, you will have all colimits in the shape of $J$ (assuming coequalizer stuff).  And, of course, you might have **all** products, not just those of a certain size, but that is just gravy and does *not* violate any sufficient condition he gives.

Given an index set $I$, we may consider a set of objects of $\mathcal{C}$ indexed by $I$.  This would be a collection of objects $\{X_i : i \in I\}$, each $X_i$ an object of $\mathcal{C}$.  We may then speak of (or, ask for the existence of) the product $\prod_{i \in I} X_i$.  This is a "product indexed by $I$."

Mac Lane is assuming that ALL such products exist whenever the index set is $\mathrm{obj}(J)$ or  $\mathrm{arr}(J)$.  This is really an assumption on the (roughly, modulo cardinalities) number of factors in such products.  If your object set is $\{a, b, c\}$ it certainly does not matter if you index a product of three terms as $X_a \times X_b \times X_c$ or $X_1 \times X_2 \times X_3$: it's still a product of three objects.